# Wrong Answer,Can't find out whats wrong in my code

Tags: c++, class, stack

I have already done this question with basic string methods,I am trying this question with stacks but getting wrong answer even my all test cases working correctly.
question link :https://www.codechef.com/problems/COMPILER
I really want to learn DSA hardly,please help me out and also give some suggestion in my coding style(i think i write code in very bad manner).

here is my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int t;
cin>>t;
while(t--){
    string str;
    cin>>str;
    class Node{
        public:
         char value;
         int indexvalue;
    };
    std::stack<Node> f;
    
    int start=0;
    int end=0;
    int k=-1;
    for(int i=0;i<str.size();i++){
        char s = str[i];
        
        if(i == 0){
            if(s == '>'){
                break;
            }
        }
     if(s=='<'){
         Node n;
         n.value=s;
         n.indexvalue=i;
         f.push(n);
     }
     else{
         if(!f.empty()){
         Node tempnode=f.top();
         f.pop();
         int tempstart=tempnode.indexvalue;
         int tempend=i;
         int tempk=tempend-tempstart;
         if(tempk>k){
             k=tempk;
              start=tempstart;
             end=tempend;
         }
         }
        
         
     }
     
    }
    cout<<k+1<<endl;
    
 }
}
```

Comment: I am confused by what is wrong. Using the example input and I get the correct output. What input are you using to get the wrong answer? https://godbolt.org/z/bMz1To

Comment: Otherwise your code looks like it should work, and from my testing it does. As for coding style, it is subject. My personal comments are: Do not use `using namespace std`, use descriptive variable names (`t`, `str`, `f` etc means nothing without context), use a `struct` instead of a `class` when using public member variable, do not declare variables that aren't used (like `start` and `end`), add comments describing why the code is doing something, split your code into smaller functions, the first break statement is not needed, use `std::max` for setting k, these are all subjective though.

Comment: When I submitting the code ,codechef pops up the wrong answer.if this question wants some index value that where the long chain started that's why I created start and end variable for future things.the first break statement is for when the string is starting with '>' so it should directly get out off the loop.